# why does my program execute an extra line("none") when executed?

Tags: python-3.x

I recently wrote a program using oop for an online coffee machine:

> from menu import Menu from coffee_maker import CoffeeMaker from
> money_machine import MoneyMachine
>
> menu = Menu() coffee_maker = CoffeeMaker() money_machine =
> MoneyMachine()
>
> is_on = True
>
> while is_on:
> choice = input(f"What would you like? {menu.get_items()}")
> if choice == "off":
> is_on = False
> elif choice == "report":
> print(coffee_maker.report())
> print(money_machine.report())

files:

> class CoffeeMaker:
> """Models the machine that makes the coffee"""
> def **init**(self):
> self.resources = {
> "water": 300,
> "milk": 200,
> "coffee": 100,
> }
>
> ```
> def report(self):
>     """Prints a report of all resources."""
>     print(f"Water: {self.resources['water']}ml")
>     print(f"Milk: {self.resources['milk']}ml")
>     print(f"Coffee: {self.resources['coffee']}g")
>
> def is_resource_sufficient(self, drink):
>     """Returns True when order can be made, False if ingredients are insufficient."""
>     can_make = True
>     for item in drink.ingredients:
>         if drink.ingredients[item] > self.resources[item]:
>             print(f"Sorry there is not enough {item}.")
>             can_make = False
>     return can_make
> ```
>
> def make_coffee(self, order):
> """Deducts the required ingredients from the resources."""
> for item in order.ingredients:
> self.resources[item] -= order.ingredients[item]
> print(f"Here is your {order.name} ☕️. Enjoy!")
>
> class MenuItem:
> """Models each Menu Item."""
> def **init**(self, name, water, milk, coffee, cost):
> self.name = name
> self.cost = cost
> self.ingredients = {
> "water": water,
> "milk": milk,
> "coffee": coffee
> }
>
> class Menu:
> """Models the Menu with drinks."""
> def **init**(self):
> self.menu = [
> MenuItem(name="latte", water=200, milk=150, coffee=24, cost=2.5),
> MenuItem(name="espresso", water=50, milk=0, coffee=18, cost=1.5),
> MenuItem(name="cappuccino", water=250, milk=50, coffee=24, cost=3),
> ]
>
> ```
> def get_items(self):
>     """Returns all the names of the available menu items"""
>     options = ""
>     for item in self.menu:
>         options += f"{item.name}/"
>     return options
>
> def find_drink(self, order_name):
>     """Searches the menu for a particular drink by name. Returns that item if it exists, otherwise returns None"""
>     for item in self.menu:
>         if item.name == order_name:
>             return item
>     print("Sorry that item is not available.")
> ```
>
> class MoneyMachine:
>
> ```
> CURRENCY = "$"
>
> COIN_VALUES = {
>     "quarters": 0.25,
>     "dimes": 0.10,
>     "nickles": 0.05,
>     "pennies": 0.01
> }
>
> def __init__(self):
>     self.profit = 0
>     self.money_received = 0
>
> def report(self):
>     """Prints the current profit"""
>     print(f"Money: {self.CURRENCY}{self.profit}")
>
> def process_coins(self):
>     """Returns the total calculated from coins inserted."""
>     print("Please insert coins.")
>     for coin in self.COIN_VALUES:
>         self.money_received += int(input(f"How many {coin}?: ")) * self.COIN_VALUES[coin]
>     return self.money_received
>
> def make_payment(self, cost):
>     """Returns True when payment is accepted, or False if insufficient."""
>     self.process_coins()
>     if self.money_received >= cost:
>         change = round(self.money_received - cost, 2)
>         print(f"Here is {self.CURRENCY}{change} in change.")
>         self.profit += cost
>         self.money_received = 0
>         return True
>     else:
>         print("Sorry that's not enough money. Money refunded.")
>         self.money_received = 0
>         return False
> ```

but it printed:

> What would you like? latte/espresso/cappuccino/report Water: 300ml
> Milk: 200ml Coffee: 100g None Money: $0 None What would you like?
> latte/espresso/cappuccino/

can you tell me how to remove this "none"?

Comment: Could you make sure your code is formatted as code? 3 tick marks (```) above and below a section of code should make sure it's formatted correctly. You seem to have done it for some chunks of code but not all.

Comment: Please read [mre]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.